# JSONVIEW.with is serilizing enum as string with @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)

Tags: java, serialization, enums

My code is:

```
final String json = getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(JsonView.with(graph)
        .onClass(clazz, match()
            .exclude(EXCLUSION_RULE)
            .include(fields)
        ));
```

I am trying to serialize enum using above code for enum. But I am getting only value and not the whole enum object even if I use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` for enum .

Comment: I am running into the same problem that enums cannot be serialized as objects when using a JsonView. Without the JsonView it works. Do you have any update on this issue? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

since you're using a JsonView to serialize whatever class/enum (clazz in your case) you are passing in, you need to annotate the desired property or getter on the class.

for example:

```
mapper.writerWithView(JsonView.<YOUR_VIEW_HERE>.class).writeValue(new File("example.json"), clazz);
```

where clazz is an instance of the following example enum:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = JSOGGenerator.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum Transmission implements Translateable<Character>{
    /**
     * automatic transmission
     */
    AUTOMATIC('A'),
    /**
     * manual transmission
     */
    MANUAL('M');

    /*... parts left out, since case shoud be clear */

    /**
     * 
     * @return key of the description as char.
     */
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(JsonView.<YOUR_VIEW_HERE>.class)
    public Character getKey() {
        return value;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the description of this <key>Transmission</key> in the given
     * <key>Locale</key>
     *
     * @return
     */
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(JsonView.<YOUR_VIEW_HERE>.class)
    public String getLabel() {
        return getLabel(this, locale);
    }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(JsonView.<YOUR_VIEW_HERE>.class)
    public Map<String, String> getKeys() {
        reloadLocale();
        return DESCRIPTIONS.get(locale);
    }

    /*... parts left out, since case shoud be clear */

    @Override
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(JsonView.<YOUR_VIEW_HERE>.class)
    public String getValue() {
        return name();
    }

}
```

further more, **do not use the annotation @JsonValue** on any of the fields, since your settings would be overruled.

*configured mapper in my case:*

```
@Component
@Primary
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
    setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true); // Better readability but larger payload. Remove this after testing
    Hibernate5Module jacksonHibernateModule = new Hibernate5Module();
    jacksonHibernateModule.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
    jacksonHibernateModule.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
    registerModule(jacksonHibernateModule);
}

}
```

*Versions:*

*jackson.version: 2.9.5*
*jackson-jsog.version: 1.1.1*

Comment: Wow I indeed forgot to annotate my desired properties :O This did the trick for me! Thank you so much.